# Run ASP.Net Core Docker Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker

I started a brand new ASP.Net Core MVC app with Docker Support enabled. It runs from within Visual Studio but I am unable to get running on the command line. Obviously I want to do this so I can push it to the repo and run from a Linux server somewhere in the cloud.

If I run `c:\>docker images` I do see the webapplication10:dev image

If I run `c:\>docker ps` I do see the container running the webapplication10:dev.

My problem is this. How do I run a container of this image on a different port. The docs seems to think this below statement should work but it doesn't. If I kill the container and try to run this, there is no container created.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 webapplication10:dev
```

> To my understanding once I run this, I should be able to browse to
>   localhost:8080 but nope, this does not work. Any ideas?

Here is the docker-compose (no surprises here, just stock standard)

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication10:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}webapplication10
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApplication10/Dockerfile
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication10/WebApplication10.csproj WebApplication10/
RUN dotnet restore WebApplication10/WebApplication10.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication10
RUN dotnet build WebApplication10.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApplication10.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication10.dll"]
```

Console window to show that docker ps still shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to browse on  `http://localhost:8000`? You should try browsing on `http://localhost:8080` as you mapping port 8080 `docker run -d -p 8080:80 webapplication10:dev`

Comment: Thanks Mohsin, but it was a typo, still does not work. I've added the console window to show that after running the command the docker ps is still empty.

Comment: Run command `docker ps -a` that will show all the containers. Find your container id and then run the command `docker logs -f {your container id}`
See if it shows any error logs preventing your docker container from launching

Comment: Thanks, got it working will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is rather simple I've learnt.

You need to EXPOSE 8080 in die Dockerfile, set to Release to build :latest tag.